# Checking if a post contains an html tag

Tags: posts, html

How can i check whether a post contains an html tag or not. suppose someone has posted an image on the post to i want to see on if the post contains an `<img>` tag similarly if there is a link so i want to check for the `<a>` tag. So is there some way i can achieve this so i can perform actions based on whether it has a particular tag or not.

I tried the has_tag() function but then realized that i refers to the wordpress post tags and then i tried to use the has_term but couldn't figure out how to work with it or maybe it's not the right function as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this if you are checking the content in the main loop.

```
$content = get_the_content();
preg_match_all('/(<img .*?>)/', $content, $img_tags);

if (!empty($img_tags)) {
    // Post content contains images, do something!
}

// Check for links and do something if you have matches
```

Comment: okay so what i can get from you code is it's checking the img tags. and what if i want to check file for a particular extension being linked or embedded? do i just remove the <img.?> and and something like mp4 or umm *.mp4?

Comment: Also do I need to put this inside a loop?